# Cómo buscar en un DataGridView un rango de fechas? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

De qué manera puedo filtrar un `DataGridView` mostrando registros que se encuentren entre dos fechas asignadas en dos `DateTimePicker`?

Este es mi código hasta ahora, pero cuando cliqueo el botón buscar no hace nada:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.Filter = "FECHA >= '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "' And " + "FECHA <= '" + DateTimePicker2.Text + "'";
End Sub
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira esta respuesta (está en inglés) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860206/how-to-use-bindingsource-filter-for-a-date-in-visual-basic-2012

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim fechaIni As String = dtpFechaIni.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Dim fechaFin As String = dtpFechaFin.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Dim sql As String = "select * from persona where fecha between'" + fechaIni + "' and '" + fechaFin + "' "

Dim adaptador2 As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion)
Dim tblFiltro As New DataTable()

adaptador2.Fill(tblFiltro)
DataGridView1.DataSource = tblFiltro
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías comentar el código y explicar como responde a la pregunta